# Как переменной result прибавить + 1, если выбран такой-то RadoButton?

Tags: c#

Вот пример кода

```
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButton1.Checked // как здесь присвоить +1 к переменной result?)
}
```

А вот обьявлена сама переменная (может что-то там не так сделал)

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам объявлять result как локальную переменную? Вам нужно объявить ее глобальной для того, чтобы с ней могли работать остальные процедуры.
Если вам действительно необходимо, чтобы result динамически отображал каждое изменение текстового поля, то вам нужны примерно такие процедуры:

```
int result;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (radioButton1.Checked)
    result = int.Parse(textBox.Text) + 1;
  else result = int.Parse(textBox.Text);
}

private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1_TextChanged(sender, e);
}
```